# Empty performance_schema.data_locks in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a remote MySQL server that runs in InnoDB engine.
I want to check the row locks used by innoDB engine when I perform a particular select query operation. For example something like this:-

```
SELECT col1,col2 ...  
FROM table1 Inner Join table2 
ON(table1.foreignkey = table2.primaryKey)
WHERE table1.id=<some_id>;
```

I read about performance_schema.data_locks table in MySQL but when I execute the above query and then afterwards try to display the contents of performance_schema.data_locks like:-

```
SELECT 
         ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID as trx_id,
         OBJECT_NAME as `table`,
         INDEX_NAME,
         LOCK_DATA,
         LOCK_MODE,
         LOCK_STATUS 
       FROM performance_schema.data_locks;
```

The above query always returns an empty set. I have tried setting autocommit to 0 but still I don't see anything in the queryset.

```
SET autocommit=0
Begin;


SELECT col1,col2 ...  
FROM table1 Inner Join table2 
ON(table1.foreignkey = table2.primaryKey);


SELECT 
         ENGINE_TRANSACTION_ID as trx_id,
         OBJECT_NAME as `table`,
         INDEX_NAME,
         LOCK_DATA,
         LOCK_MODE,
         LOCK_STATUS 
       FROM performance_schema.data_locks;
```

This flow always gives empty set. Although performance_schema variable is set to ON.

What can I do to see the row locks used by InnoDB.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What lets you think that your SELECT query should lock anything?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel InnoDB operated in repeatable read mode by default.I suppose that even for reads, innoDB has to perform next-key locking for the particular rows that are read. I read from the docs here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking.html.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the docs right. They talk about preventing [Phantom Rows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html) - But there the only example is using `FOR UPDATE` and `WHERE`. If it's just about repeatable/consistent (non-writing) **reads** - AFAIK they use logs (snapshots) rather than locks. But I'm not an expert :-) .. see [consistent read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_consistent_read)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I am not sure I understand the concept properly. I think you are right, snapshots are used for reads as mentioned in the docs. Also is [consistent read](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_consistent_read) performed even when we have a `WHERE` clause along with `SELECT` in the query. Because it looks like `WHERE` clause is still repeatable/consistent(non-writing) read. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[15.15.2 InnoDB INFORMATION_SCHEMA Transaction and Locking Information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-information-schema-transactions.html)

> data_locks: This Performance Schema table contains a row for each hold lock and each lock request that is blocked waiting for a held lock to be released:

> There is one row for each held lock, whatever the state of the transaction that holds the lock (INNODB_TRX.TRX_STATE is RUNNING, LOCK WAIT, ROLLING BACK or COMMITTING).

> Each transaction in InnoDB that is waiting for another transaction to release a lock (INNODB_TRX.TRX_STATE is LOCK WAIT) is blocked by exactly one blocking lock request. That blocking lock request is for a row or table lock held by another transaction in an incompatible mode. A lock request always has a mode that is incompatible with the mode of the held lock that blocks the request (read vs. write, shared vs. exclusive).

> The blocked transaction cannot proceed until the other transaction commits or rolls back, thereby releasing the requested lock. For every blocked transaction, data_locks contains one row that describes each lock the transaction has requested, and for which it is waiting.

Comment: Okay so data_locks will not give me the requested locks by my query untill and unless it is blocked by some other transaction with conflicting / incompatible locks. So is there any way to directly know the requested locks by my query other than forcefully blocking the table on write using another connection.

Comment: For example, SELECT ... FOR SHARE sets an IS lock, and SELECT ... FOR UPDATE sets an IX lock. Then check lock.